# Webdriver Jenkins (remote linux) build fails but runs from my local machine(windows)

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I've currently been using webdriver from my local machine and now trying to run my tests on a remote machine using Jenkins. When I create my build it fails consistently. When my tests run the following error is displayed `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test`
When I edit my pom.xml file and change it from 2.48 to 2.44 I see a browser error instead. I'm confused what changes I should make.
pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>Training</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Training</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.48.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

This is the error message displayed when I create my build and selenium is 2.48

```
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:212)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:634)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoFailed(Maven3Builder.java:667)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:232)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:325)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.713s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jan 09 00:25:22 GMT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/490M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project Training: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
[ERROR] at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
[ERROR] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[ERROR] at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2556)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1412)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
[ERROR] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1273)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1260)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1114)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/tango/.jenkins/jobs/PMI_Selenium_Automation_Policy/workspace/pom.xml to Framework/Training/1/Training-1.pom
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
channel stopped
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check your JVM config on Jenkins,it seems you are running an older version, can you upgrade the JVM/JDK on jenkins you need Java 7 or more.

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: Jenkins is already succesfully making builds for other projects, so is it possible it is not a java probblem?